# Sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$U_1 := \{(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3) \in \Re^3 : \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 = 0\}$$ $$ U_2 := \{ (\lambda, \lambda, \lambda) : \lambda \in \Re \}$$

be subspaces. Show that $U_1 + U_2 = \Re^3$.

The sum of the two subspaces $U_1 + U_2$ is by definition $\{u_1 + u_2 : u_1\in U_1, u_2 \in U_2\}$. If $v\in \Re^3 $ is some arbitrary element, then this means that $v = u_1 + u_2$ for some $u_1$ and $u_2$. But I don't see how you can create every element of $\Re^3$ on that way. By adding $(\lambda, \lambda, \lambda)$ I can create all multiples of a given $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3)$, but since $\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 = 0$, the gammas are always in a fixed proportion, so that two gammas always equal the remaining one or all are equal to 0, and I don't see how I can create elements from $\Re^3$ in which all three gammas are different.
Is the statement $U_1 + U_2 = \Re^3$ true? Can someone give me a hint please or tell me whether I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create every element $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ it the following way.
$$(x,y,z) = (x-b,y-b,2b-x-y)+(b,b,b)$$ where $b=\frac{x+y+z}{3}$

Answer (score 3):

It's simple to see that $\dim U_1+\dim U_2=2+1=\dim\mathbb R^3$ and that $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}$ hence we have
$$\mathbb R^3=U_1\oplus U_2$$